# Fallar or decepcionar

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I want to say, Spain is famous for it's festivals, las Fallas don't disappoint.

Is it "Las Fallas no fallan" or "no decepcionan". Or is it something else?

I have checked everywhere and am still unsure.

Thanks.

Comment: You should provide some context, like Valencia. Be aware that the idiomatic usage of disappoint like that cannot be translated literally. In Spanish, you would say: Las Fallas are marvelous or something like that. What do you mean you checked everywhere??

Comment: Yes,Las Fallas de Valencia.

Comment: I looked in the dictionaries and online,thanks

Comment: I said, Spain is famous for its festivals and Las Fallas do not disappoint.

Comment: I think you can use here: no defraudar las expectativas. You did not say in your question that Spain is famous for its festivals. You need to add that to your question.

Comment: OK,defraudar las expectivas is an option. Are the other options I gave wrong and only for a different Use?

Comment: Idiomatic uses can't be translated **literally**.

Comment: I think "Las Fallas no fallan" is an effective play on words.

Comment: @Gustavson The English is not a play on words and one would not translate fallas anyway.

Comment: @Lambie OP seems to be interested in the best way to express "Las Fallas won't disappoint" in Spanish. Otherwise, OP would not be asking the question here.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, as long as there is a commercial interest in encouraging attending Las Fallas and considering the added value of plays on words in advertising, a good translation would be:

- Las Fallas no fallan.

According to [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/fallar), the fourth acceptation of "fallar" is "go wrong" or "stop working properly", but the third one is "fail to meet somebody's expectations":

> 3. intr. Dicho de una cosa o de una persona: No responder como se espera. Tú me estás fallando.
> 4. intr. Dicho de una cosa: Dejar de funcionar bien. Fallar el corazón, la televisión.

Answer (score 1):

If I read "Las fallas no fallan", I'd think Las Fallas won't fail.
If I read "Las fallas no decepcionan", I'd think Las Fallas won't dissapoint.

You can use "fallar" as "to dissapoint", but in this case it uses an indirect object. It would be "Fallarle (a alguien)" = "let (somebody) down". I wrote an example of each case below. So you could say "Las fallas no te fallan". Or "Las fallas no le fallan" (a usted), depending on the context.

Two examples of "fallar", the 1st one means dissapoint and the 2nd means fail:

- Don't let me down -> No me falles  (dissapoint)
- Don't fail                -> No falles            (fail)

As an earlier asnswer stated, using "fallar" sounds great because of the play on words.

Answer (score 0):

**[Las Fallas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falles)** is the name of the typical festival of Valencia, as *San Fermín* it's from the Basque country. It has nothing to do with the verb *fallar* (fail), the origin is different.

> The word *Fallas* derives from the Latin facula, which means "torch", over the centuries it has evolved to give its name to the *San José* festivities that are celebrated in Valencia and other locations.

– Las Fallas don't disappoint – means that everyone will have fun during this holiday in Valencia.

Comment: Yes, can anyone give me a natural expression that fits the meaning in English Please?  I am not sure about my verbs.

Comment: – Las Fallas don't disappoint –  is correct = Las Fallas no decepcionan.

Comment: I recommend: "Las Fallas no fallan". Effective and to the point.